# Changing values of digits of an algebraic irrational number

Tags: nt.number-theory

Consider the set of irrationals $\mathbb{I} \cap (0,1)$. Define the map $f$ that takes
$x= \sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{a_n}{3^n}$ to $\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{ \phi(a_n)}{3^n}$, where $\phi$ is the permutation of $\{0,1,2\}$, $0\mapsto 1 \mapsto 2\mapsto 0$.  Is it possible that both $x$ and $f(x)$ are algebraic for some $x$ ?

The common belief is that they are "random". A solution would not run contrary to that. Still my feeling is that this would not be possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $x_j = \sum_{n \geq 1} \mathrm{1}_{a_n=j} 3^{-n}$. Then 
$$
x_0 + x_1 + x_2 = \frac{1}{2} \\
x_1 + 2x_2 = x \\
x_0 + 2x_1 = f(x).
$$
If $x$ and $f(x)$ are algebraic then the equations above would yield that $x_j$ is algebraic for each $j$. It is conjectured and generally believed that any irrational algebraic number is normal in all bases. Since $x_j$ is obviously not normal in base $3$, this conjecture would imply that $x_j$ is rational for each $j$, and thus that $x$ is rational.

Comment: Ah, that's very clever! This would break down say in base $\ge 4$ though, right?

Answer (score 7):

Just to augment @js21's answer. The question of whether irrational $x_i$ are necessarily transcendent is equivalent to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/114758/). As the answer suggests, even this specific question is wide open, or at least was such in 2012.

As for the other bases $b>2$, the result is similar. Defining $x_i$ as in js21's answer, you get that
$$
  x_{b-1}=\frac{x+\frac1{b-1}-f(x)}{b}
$$
is algebraic though not normal. (Surely, if $x_{b-1}$ is just rational, then $x-(b-1)x_{b-1}$ will be an algebraic irrational though not normal.)

Comment: That's right! Great answer, thanks!