# Subsequence of a sequence of digits of an algebraic irrational number

Tags: nt.number-theory, algorithmic-randomness

Consider an algebraic irrational number in $(0,1)$ with binary expansion
$x = \sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{a_n}{2^n}$. Is it  possible that the number $\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{a_{2n}}{2^n}$ is again algebraic irrational ?

My opinion is no. Heuristics: it should be difficult to determine binary expansions of other algebraic irrationals, even if we have a supply of other expansions, except for trivial operations. My previous question (see [link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/283331/changing-values-of-digits-of-an-algebraic-irrational-number)) is of a similar flavor.

Comment: Do you really mean what you've just written down, or $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{a_{2n}}{2^{2n}}$ ?

Comment: Most likely the answer is not known...

Comment: @Loïc Teyssier: Correct, what is written down.

Comment: Ok, only to check (though I guess it wouldn't make the question any easier).

Comment: It might be fun to do some experiments here. Take some such algebraic irrational, maybe $\sqrt2-1$, apply your operation to it, and then feed the result into the Inverse Symbolic Calculator or into an integer-relation finder like PSLQ, and see whether anything interesting comes out.